# Anchor Link Toggle Class

Tags: jquery, class, menu, toggle

I have a menu that looks like:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" onclick="closeNav();">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" onclick="closeNav();">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#products" onclick="closeNav();">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" onclick="closeNav();">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#howitworks" onclick="closeNav();">How it Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" onclick="closeNav();">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is set home to be the default class and then when another link is chosen, the active class gets removed from home and added to the chosen anchor link.

I thought I could do this with jQuery toggleClass, but the active class stays with home and then every single link gets the `active` class.

```
$("#nav li").click(function(){
    $("a").toggleClass("active");
});
```

I'm not sure if I'm using this right, but it's definitely not working how I expected.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/0tgzfm7b/

Comment: `$("#nav li").removeClass("active");
$(this).closest("li").addClass("active");`

Comment: You've added `active` class to your `li` but your jquery toggles it on the `a` - none of the `a`s have the class at the start, so they all get it via the code.  From the HTML, use `$("#nav li").toggleClass("active");` / from the jquery, use `<li><a class='active' ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to toggle the LIs

```js
$("#nav li").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
  // here you can close the divs and open the one belonging to the clicked one
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#howitworks">How it Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In event listener call back you can specified a parameter who will be this event himself.
This event is an object containing a reference to the clicked element called "currentTarget", you can use this reference to interact to the element who fired the event.

```
$("#nav li").click(function(event){
    $("#nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(event.currentTarget).addClass("active");
});
```